# Is there a better implementation to extract a multiline text structure from one file based on the index from the other file?

Tags: perl

I have two files. One is a file of table creation strings dumped from database, the other is the name of tables, with a "prompt" as a prefix and a "..." as suffix. Just as below:
file A (index):

```
prompt branch...
prompt branch_param...
prompt branch_pre_param...
prompt business...
prompt business_map...
prompt business_type...
```

file B (dump):

```
CREATE TABLE "KS"."BRANCH"
 ("BRANCH_CODE"       CHARACTER(3)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "BRANCH_NAME"       CHARACTER(40)   NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "PARAM_LEVEL"       INTEGER         NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0
 )
  DATA CAPTURE NONE
 IN "LONG_DATA_TBS";


CREATE TABLE "KS"."BRANCH2BANK"
 ("BRANCH_CODE"         CHARACTER(3)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "BANK_CODE"           CHARACTER(6)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "ACC_COMP_RESULT"     CHARACTER(1)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT ''
 )
  DATA CAPTURE NONE
 IN "SMALL_TBS";

CREATE TABLE "KS"."BRANCH2BOND"
 ("BRANCH_CODE"        CHARACTER(3)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "BOND_CODE"          CHARACTER(8)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "BOND_NAME"          CHARACTER(20)   NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "TOTAL_AMT"          DECIMAL(19, 4)  NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
  "FINANCING_CUST_NO"  CHARACTER(10)   NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "SET_DATE"           CHARACTER(8)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "SET_TIME"           CHARACTER(8)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "SET_EMP"            CHARACTER(6)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "SPARE1"             CHARACTER(20)   NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "SPARE2"             CHARACTER(20)   NOT NULL  DEFAULT ''
 )
  DATA CAPTURE NONE
 IN "SMALL_TBS";

CREATE TABLE "KS"."BRANCH_PARAM"
 ("BRANCH_CODE"    CHARACTER(3)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "PARAM_CODE"     CHARACTER(4)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "SET_DATE"       CHARACTER(8)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "SET_TIME"       CHARACTER(8)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT ''
 )
  DATA CAPTURE NONE
 IN "SMALL_TBS";

CREATE TABLE "KS"."BRANCH_RESERVE_CREDIT_STOCK"
 ("BRANCH_CODE"  CHARACTER(3)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT '',
  "SET_TIME"     CHARACTER(8)    NOT NULL  DEFAULT ''
 )
  DATA CAPTURE NONE
 IN "TX_DATA_TBS"
 INDEX IN "TX_INDEX_TBS";
```

I have written a perl implementation, but I think it is much too ugly and inefficient. Is there a better way to improve this?

my code: (rewritten with Richard and lilydjwg's advice) (last version)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.016;

my (%hash,$cont);
open IN,'<',shift;
while(<IN>){
    chomp;
    $hash{$1}=1 if /prompt (\w+)\.\.\./;
}
close IN;
open IN,'<',shift;
while(<IN>){
    chomp;
    $cont = (defined $hash{lc $1}?say "prompt $1..." : 0) if /CREATE TABLE "KS"\."(\w+)"/;
    say if $cont == 1;
}
close IN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably it's the repeated reads you don't like.

So - read the CREATE TABLE file once, checking for:

```
CREATE TABLE "KS"."(\w+)"
```

Then you can build up the table definition until the next CREATE TABLE at which point you put the table-definition into a hash keyed by the table-name.

Then, read your prompts and grab the definitions one by one from the hash printing them out.

Alternatively, you could just read the CREATE TABLE file into a single string and search+replace the table-name part since that's all you seem to be changing at the moment. The first approach is more flexible though.

---

Edit:
You could make the defined bit a little clearer perhaps with:

```
while ($line=<IN>) {
    chomp($line);
    if (/CREATE TABLE "KS"\."(\w+)"/ && $hash{lc $1}) {
        $line = ...
    }
    say $line;
}
```

I like to use an explicit variable in my while-loops once I get beyond a couple of lines too.

Comment: Very thanks. I have rewritten the code with a hashtable (see the OP I edited). But I am still not very satisfied with the control flow when reading file B to create the hashtable. Are there any common practices in Perl?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that file A is relatively small. You can read and build a set (or the like) from it which contains all the table names. Then read and identify on the SQL dump file, for each table creation statement, check if that table name is in your set.

I don't quite know Perl, but this Python code seems what you want:

```
import sys

tableNames = {x[7:-3] for l in open(sys.argv[1]) if x.startswith('prompt ')}

for l in open(sys.argv[2]):
  if l.startswith('CREATE TABLE "KS"."'):
    name = l.split('"')[4].lower()
    if name in tableNames:
      print("prompt {0}...\nCreate table{0}(".format(name))
  print(l, end='')
```

Comment: How is the process of "read and identify on the SQL dump file" going on? Would you explain it in detail?

Comment: If I am not wrong, it only prints out the line of "CREATE TABLE XXXXXX" after the line of "prompt xxxxx". How about the body part (the column definitions and so on)?

Comment: @Lord_WayneY, oh, you can just do the similar. I'll update the code in a while.

Comment: Although your code still have a bug, I think I've caught your idea. I also modified my code to read file A first, so that it would build a smaller hashtable.